# sys.path and os.getcwd() in disagreement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, sys

I have a python script under my current directory named `sub/code.py`. The `sub` directory has other scripts and an `__init__.py`, so it acts as a package.

From my current directory:

```
python -i sub/code.py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path[0]
'/home/name/folder/current_directory/sub'
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home/name/folder/current_directory'
>>>
```

Are `os.getcwd()` and `sys.path[0]` supposed to disagree in this way?  As I understand it, both of them should refer to the current directory, but in this case only `os.getcwd()` does.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `sys.path[0]` is an empty string, which evaluates to the current directory.

Perhaps there is code in your `sub` module that manipulates `sys.path`?

Comment: Definitely not, `sys` is not even imported.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer the OP's question.

I experienced that the behavior from `os.getcwd()` on Mac OSX differs compared to what it does e.g. in php.

test_getcwd.py:

```
from os import getcwd
print (getcwd())
```

outputs the current user path, not the path of the running script:

```
Michaels-MacBook-Air:~ michag$ python3 /Users/michag/Documents/aaa_raspbian/ddpos_ddpi_3/boot/test_getcwd.py
/Users/michag
```

where /Users/michag equals to ~, which is obviously the same.

Answer (score 0):

Say you are in a directory `/` that contains sub directory `d` and directory `d` has a python file `f.py` as such:

```
import os
import sys

print(f'sys.path[0]: {sys.path[0]}')
print(f'os.getcwd(): {os.getcwd()}')
```

Then `python ./d/f.py` will output:

```
sys.path[0]: /d
os.getcwd(): /
```

If you change directory into `/d` (with cd /d), then `python ./f.y` will output:

```
sys.path[0]: /d
os.getcwd(): /d
```

From these results (on Linux Unbuntu with python 3.8) it seems that:

- `os.getcwd()` outputs the directory from which the command is
  executed and
- `sys.path[0]` outputs the directory in which the file you execute is.

Note: Both paths seem to be absolute paths (aka full paths).